# CSS inheritance: applying selector for itself and every descendant

Tags: css, inheritance, css-selectors

Get a custom user CSS and type this

```
.answered-accepted {
  color: white !important;
  background: #090 !important;
}
```

Now go to [answers.unity3d](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions?sort=hot) and look for an accepted answer. The design looks bad, because the `<strong>` in there overrides the customization. The fix I've found is this:

```
.answered-accepted, .answered-accepted * {
  color: white !important;
  background: #090 !important;
}
```

Now it looks fine on the website, but the code looks ugly!! How can I do this without repeating the class name?

Comment: I'd be interested to see any answers which explain why the user CSS doesn't work. From my reading of http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade, the !important rules should override the conflicting declarations, even though the original declarations have higher specificity

Comment: Just as a note, and agreeing with @Dancrumb, I will accept an answer here any time it comes, as long as I get notified somehow. I'm not all that prominent active on the website so the current "automated" notification system might not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
.answered-accepted strong {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: I'd have to add all that as a second rule! That's even uglier! Plus it doesn't work at all - the problem isn't that it's bold, it's that the strong class overrides the parent div. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
.answered-accepted strong {
  font-weight: inherit;
}
```

This will make the `<strong>` inherit the font-weight from the most direct parent so you can keep all the data in one place. You can `inherit` any other properties you want the `<strong>` to take from `.answer-accepted`.

Only problem is that IE7 and earlier don't support it, so you may still need your hack....

Comment: While that seems to work today, I can't really try it anymore. The site has changed and it's now accepting the first suggested code in my question. But thanks for the reply! ^_^